# The Isolation of sessions data across multi domain frames

Tags: php, session, iframe, cookies, http-post

Site A of `www.cheese.com` is trying to embed site B, of `www.apple.com`, inside of it in an iframe.

Both Site A and site B use their array of $_SESSION variables. Both invoke `session_start()`.

Site B can only be accessed if it is passed a set of correct key value pairs (username and password) within the body of a http post request.

A problem occurs when I attempt this scenerio. I believe it is related to site A's session getting mixed with site B's session.

Is there anyway to isolate the two site's sessions from each other during and after the http post?

Comment: Are you transmitting the session ID in the URL and hosting both sites on the same server? Otherwise, it's impossible to share session data unless you build a fairly complex system.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! Store the session data in a different folder using `session_save_path`. This will save the session data to an arbitrary folder on the server. However, this will not solve your entire problem - by "a problem occurs", what do you refer to as a problem?

(Comment the answer and I'll edit my answer to provide further guidelines)